# How do I make a deep copy of a dynamically created element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically generate 8 new paragraphs with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnhoffman/Dfydn/

However, this snippet of jQuery only adds a single paragraph to my div (with the text "7" in it).

```
var attached = $("<p>");
var sandbox = $("#sandbox");

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    // How come reseting attached works? attached = $("<p>");
    attached.html(i).appendTo(sandbox);
}​
```

HTML: `<div id="sandbox"></div>​`

I do not want to run `attached = $("<p>");` for every iteration of the loop because I want to make use of the prototype design pattern - I want to build a paragraph and then alter copies of it to preventing having to build from scratch every time. How do I make a deep copy of a dynamically created element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this. Use the `.clone()` method. Also you don't need the .html(i) when you're using clone(). Because clone returns a jQuery object you don't even need to wrap a $() around it.

```
var attached = $("<p>"); 
var sandbox = $("#sandbox");

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    attached.clone().appendTo(sandbox); 
}
```

​Also if you want to clone the event handlers you should use .clone(true). See http://api.jquery.com/clone/ for more info about `clone()`

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `.clone()` method is precisely for [making deep copies](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).  From the documentation:

> Description: Create a deep copy of the set of matched elements.

Example:

```
var attached = $("<p>");
var sandbox = $("#sandbox");    

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $(attached).clone().appendTo(sandbox);
}​
```

Comment: You're selecting all current `p` elements from the DOM instead of creating and cloning a new one. I don't think that's what's intended. Also, `"p .copyme"` should be `"p.copyme"`.

Comment: Thanks for the input--I misunderstood the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
var attached = $("<p>");
var sandbox = $("#sandbox");

for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    // How come reseting attached works? attached = $("<p>");
    attached.clone().html(i).appendTo(sandbox);
}​
```